# React Native Maps handling large amount of markers

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have to display above 1000 markers on map. I am using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps). But the phone becomes unresponsive. Any idea how to display large data on maps?

Answer (score 3):

**Marker clustering** is what you are looking for.
Unfortunately, *react-native-maps* doesn't support it, yet. There is an [issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/213) and [PR](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/pull/137) though.

Easiest solution for now is to use [react-native-map-clustering](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering) module on top of *react-native-maps*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will look into it